# regex inside HTML Tag

Tags: php, regex

My regex `(<(div|i)\b[^>]*>)(\bTEST\b)(<\/(div|i)\s*>)`

replace = 'MOM'
From

```
<div clas="dfsdf">TEST</div>
```

is

```
MOM
```

But I want the HTML tag persists
It should look like this:  `<div clas="dfsdf">MOM</div>`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use regex, when working with HTML. There are plenty of other, better ways ... using a DOM like interface.

Comment: please see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/797393

Answer (score 0):

If you just replace with `MOM`, your whole match will be replaced by `MOM`..In your regex `<div clas="dfsdf">` is group 1 ($1), `TEST` is capture group 3 ($3) and `</div>` is group 4 ($4)... So, you have to replace it with the following

```
$1MOM$4
```

to contain what is required and replace just the capture group corresponding to `TEST`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [look around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
preg_replace('~(?<=<(?:div|i)\b[^>]*>)TEST(?=</\s*(?:div|i)\s*>)~', "MOM', $str);
```